# Trim consecutive duplicate characters

Tags: php, regex

So I'm creating urls for my pages by doing the following:

```
$uri = strtolower($info->name);
$uri = str_replace('&','and',$uri);

$uri = $info->id."-".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','-',$uri);
```

Basically I make everything lowercase, change `&` to `and` and change all special characters to a `-`. My only problem now if for instance `$info->name` is `this is - a string` it will show up as `this-is---a-string`.

I would like this to become `this-is-a-string` without doing something like `str_replace('---','-',$input);`

I figure I need a regular expression for this, but I'm horrible at those so I was wondering if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
$uri = $info->id."-".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','-',$uri);
```

to

```
$uri = $info->id."-".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/','-',$uri);
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it'd be that simple. I need to learn to search better :) Cheers! - will accept when it's possible