# How to convert all non-alphanumerical characters of a string to hyphens?

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert all the non-alphanumerical characters to hyphens (-) (dashes) for an elegant URL. For this purpose I am using the following method:

```
$title = 'Any Authentic PHP Script / Third Party & @ 10 $ tool to'; 
$title .= 'Convert HTML to BBcode, BBcode to HTML';
$url = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/m", "", $title );
$url = preg_replace("/ /", "-", $url);
```

It outputs the following:

```
Any-Authentic-PHP-Script--Third-Party---10--tool-to-Convert-HTML-to-BBcode-BBcode-to-HTML
```

But, as you will have noticed, there are some unwanted double hyphens (`--`) and some triple hyphens (`--`) in the output. I want only one hyphen between each word. How can I achieve my target?

Comment: Duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6979888/2106973

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your code, just replace

```
$url = preg_replace("/ /", "-", $url);
```

to

```
$url = preg_replace("/\s+/", "-", $url);
```

And get all your spaces (and tabs and so on) convert to only one hyphen. `\s` means any space character, and `+` means one or more of the previous token

However, you can do better. Replace *both* your regexes into one `preg_replace`

```
$url = preg_replace("/\W+/m", "-", $title );
```

...because `\W` precisely mean non-alphanumeric characters.

In addition, if you also don't want underscores (`_`) in your result, use

```
$url = preg_replace("/[\W_]+/m", "-", $title );
```

---

As a side note, next time if you genuinely want to do

```
preg_replace("/ /", "-", $url);
```

please do this instead

```
str_replace(" ", "-", $url);
```

Because `str_replace` is much faster than `preg_replace` and is even recommended from PHP docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

> If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace().

Comment: Shouldn't you use `[\W_]+` instead since \W+ will not match underscores?

Comment: @Jerry noted, included in my answer

Answer (score 2):

It's because first all non-alphanumerical characters are removed, so your string becomes

```
Any Authentic PHP Script  Third Party   10  tool to
```

You're seeing it already—leaving double spaces at some places.

Just do this:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "-", $subject);
```

It replaces all occurences of *one or multiple* non-alphanumerical characters to a single dash.

Comment: You have a typo in your code, should be A-Z not A-A